# How to check the checkbox without Id/Class using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How to check the checkbox without Id/Class using javascript?

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">bike
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">car
</form>
```

Comment: What selector would you like to use? [There are about a dozen unrelated to class or id](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In javascript**:

You can use `document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']")[0]` for the first one and `document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']")[1]` for the second one.

To check them all you need to use `document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']")`

In other words:

```
First_checkbox = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']")[0];
Second_checkbox = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']")[1];
```

Something you can do with the `document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']")` tag:

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']")[1].checked = true;
document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']")[1].checked = false;
```

**In jQuery**:

You can use `$(":checkbox")[0]` for the first one and `$(":checkbox")[1]` for the second one.

To check them all you need to use `$(":checkbox")`

In other words:

```
First_checkbox = $(":checkbox")[0];
Second_checkbox = $(":checkbox")[1];
```

Something you can do with the `$(":checkbox")` tag:

```
$(":checkbox")[1].checked = true;
$(":checkbox")[1].checked = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you are looking for `getElementsByName()` [more on this here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp).

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector("input[name='vehicle'][value='Bike']").checked = true
```

I think it's self-documenting. [Article about attribute selectors](http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/).