# change text color when checked check box without ID and class attribute in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the color of the text when the checkbox is checked. 
First of all, i would like to inform that i'm not allowed to add any ID or class attribute to it.
Here is the example code.

```
 <label style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold;">I have read and agree to the terms and conditions
 <input type="checkbox" name="termsChkbx" />
 </label>
```

As i know, we can use

> document.getElementById()
>
> document.getElementsByTagName()
>
> document.getElemntsByClassName()

i've tried this but it doesn't work.

```
<script>
        function myFunction() {
    var chkbox = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
    if(chkbox.checked){
        document.getElementsByTagName("label").style.color = "#000000";
    }
}
</script>
```

Since the code do not contain any ID and Class attribute.
So how can it be done?

Comment: You can't access an element with no ID or class unless you use JQuery, why not just add an ID ?

Comment: @KobyDouek Actually you can, with [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). Although you're right that adding an ID would be easier

Comment: @qxz What if he has more than 1 label ?

Comment: @KobyDouek [`:nth_child()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo)?

Comment: What is your browser support level?  Are `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll` options for you?  Also, are you _unable_ to add a class or id?

Comment: As the checkbox has a `name`, you could also use [`document.getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign a click handler and pass current element to it. Then you can navigate to parent using current element and update its properties.

```js
function updateColor(el){
  el.parentNode.style.color = el.checked ? "blue" : "#FF0000"
}
```

```html
<label style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold;">I have read and agree to the terms and conditions
 <input type="checkbox" name="termsChkbx" onclick="updateColor(this)"/>
 </label>
```

**querySelector Approach**

```js
function updateColor(){
  this.parentNode.style.color = this.checked ? "blue" : "#FF0000"
}

var chks = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="termsChkbx"]');

for(var i =0; i< chks.length; i++){
  chks[i].addEventListener("click", updateColor)
}
```

```html
<label style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold;">I have read and agree to the terms and conditions
 <input type="checkbox" name="termsChkbx"/>
 </label>
```

Comment: for this line var chks = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="termsChkbx"]') ,  is it it will only select the input type with the name ="termsChkbx"?? if we do not mention the name="termChkbx" it will change the color of every input type?

Comment: Yes. You can do something like `.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')` but its a bad practice to use element selector as it will affect lot more elements than required. If it is possible for you to add class to then that would be better, but if not, you can attach event on all and then have filter in it to update only necessary elements

Answer (score 4):

A pure `CSS` solution, with some change in HTML structure.

```css
input[type=checkbox]:checked + span{
  color:blue !important;
  font-weight:normal !important;
}
```

```html
<label style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold;">
 <input type="checkbox" name="termsChkbx" />
 <span>I have read and agree to the terms and conditions</span>
 
 </label>
```

Comment: Great idea to use pure CSS... can't believe I didn't think of that

Comment: Doesn't address the issue of possibly having multiple checkboxes, though-- may I suggest changing to `input[type=checkbox][name=termsChkbx]:checked + span`?

Comment: @anied point is to change the color of text with selection of checkbox, also what if you want same functionality on checkbox having different name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jqueryselector (it will select al the element and put them in an array and then select the element [0] of it 
`First_checkbox = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']")[0];`

Comment: 'jqueryselector'? huh?

Comment: Font: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731973/how-to-check-the-checkbox-without-id-class-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `jQuery`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type=checkbox]").on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("black");
  })
})
```

```css
.black{
color:black !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold;">I have read and agree to the terms and conditions
 <input type="checkbox" name="termsChkbx" />
 </label>
```